# How is ? different then saying object?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, methods, wildcard

I have written the below method with and without a wildcard.  In the first instance, how is different then subsituting in object for the wildcard?

```
public void sumOfNumbers(List<? extends Number>numbers){
    int sum=0;
    for(Number n:numbers){
        sum+=n.intValue();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

In this method without the wildcard shown below why can it put  in the parameter?

```
public<T extends Number> void sumOfNumbers(List<T>numbers){
    int sum=0;
    for(Number n:numbers){
        sum+=n.intValue();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Lastly, if ? extends Number then why cant I have an Integer in the for each loop as shown below?

```
 public void sumOfNumbers(List<? extends Number>numbers){
    int sum=0;
    for(Integer n:numbers){//Why cant I do this??
        sum+=n.intValue();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Also, why can you put number in the for each loop, in this case isnt Integer the upper bounds? Isnt that below number?

```
public void sumOfNumbers(List<? extends Integer>numbers){
    int sum=0;
    for(Integer n:numbers){//Why cant I do this??
        sum+=n.intValue();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking in the first case - are you asking why you can't write `List<Object extends Number>`, or `List<Object>`, or... what?

Comment: "why cant I have an Integer in the for each loop" because your list isn't necessarily composed of `Integer`s - what if it is a `List<Double>`?

Comment: Yes, that is true, but based on the Upper bounds rule of extend shouldnt it work?

Comment: `List<? extends Number>` means "a list of some unknown type, that is or extends Number". So it could be a List<Integer>, or a List<Float>, or a List<Double>, you just don't know. The only thing you know is that it contains instances of Number.

Comment: But isnt Integer a type of number? Therefore, shouldnt it work?

Comment: Yes, `Integer extends Number` - but so do `Double`, `Float`, `Short` etc. If you've got a `List<Double>`, you can't cast its elements to an `Integer`.

Comment: Your last example compiles just fine for me. You *can* do that, because every element in `numbers` is an `Integer`.

Comment: You got your logic backward. If you have a box of fruits, you can't say that the fruits are apples. The fact that an apple is a fruit doesn't change anything. It could be a box of bananas or pears. And a banana is not an apple.

Comment: `Also, why can you put number in the for each loop, in this case isnt Integer the upper bounds? Isnt that below number?` Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

First off, let's describe what you are doing when you say `<T extends Number>`. What this says in the compiler's mind is, "Use T as a reference to a generic that must extend the `Number` class". So, to address your first question,

> In the first instance, how is different then subsituting in object for the wildcard?

you're really not doing anything, "different". All you are doing is saying "Use the **word** Object as a reference to a generic that..." In fact, if you were to try doing this:

```
public class Subclass<java.lang.Object extends Number>
```

the compiler will complain: `Check class headers... parsing individual files failed!` This is because you aren't actually using an `Object`, but the **word** Object. See [Type Parameter Naming Conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) in the generics tutorial about this.

Refer to [dorukayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131909/how-is-different-then-saying-object/38132161#38132161)'s answer for the answer to the other two questions.

Answer (score 1):

> I have written the below method with and without a wildcard. In the first instance, how is different then subsituting in object for the wildcard?

The method will be way harder to use if you substitute `Object` for the question mark.

```
class Foo<T>{}

class Bar{
    static void barfoo(Foo<Object> foo){}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        barfoo(new Foo<Bar>()); // Doesn't compile
    }
}
```

> In this method without the wildcard shown below why can it put in the parameter?

The method has a type parameter `T` which `extends Number`. Thanks to this type parameter, the compiler knows that any `List<T>` passed to that method will contain numbers.

> if ? extends Number then why cant I have an Integer in the for each loop as shown below?

What if `numbers` isn't a `List` of `Integer`s? Because its type parameter only has to extend `Number`, it might also be `Double`s. Or `Long`s. Or even `BigDecimal`s.